# How to achieve concept of connection list with minimal cost using rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

Say User A is connected to B, then user B is automatically considered to be  connected with user A.

`User` `has_many` `connection`

Connection Table:

`id, user_id, connected_user_id`

Say

---

`id || user_id|| connected_user_id`

`1  ||  1     ||     2`

`2  ||  3     ||     1`

`3  ||  2     ||     3`

---

---

Expected outcome:

`User.find(1).connections`

> [< User id:2, ... >,< User id:3, ... > ]

`User.find(2).connections`

> [< User id:1, ... >, < User id:3, ... >]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a many-to-many relationship, which it sounds like you do, you can set up a [has_many through relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :connections
  has_many :connected_users, through: :connections
end

class Connection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :connected_user, class_name: "User"
end
```

Then to find all connections like you want you can create a method in your User class:

```
def get_connections
  User.find(Connection.where(user_id: self.id).connected_user_ids + Connection.where(connected_user_id: self.id).user_ids)
end
```

`User.find(1).get_connections` should return

> [< User id:2, ... >,< User id:3, ... > ]

Comment: why connected_user_id is taken as reference in user table ?

Comment: @Manish you do need to add a connected_user_id column to your users table to serve as the reference to the other user's id. I updated my answer with sample migrations to do so.

Comment: Don't you think it is not the right way, as it will create multiple record entries for multiple connections for the same user ?

Comment: @Manish updated the answer to provide an option if you need a many-to-many relationship, which is sounds like do.

Comment: Thank you for trying at least, But what I am expecting is not achieved. User.find(1).connections will return me only [< User id:2, ... >] and expected outcome is  [< User id:2, ... >,< User id:3, ... > ]

Comment: I am rather simplifying it as A is brother of B and C is Brother of A, so when I need an association to find A's brothers, expected outcome is B,C. 

Where `Connection` model will hold the relation between Users
`id || user_id|| connected_user_id`

`1  ||  A     ||     B`

`2  ||  C     ||     A`

which clearly indicates A has two brothers B,C.

Comment: @Manish Ah, apologies for my misunderstanding. Not enough coffee this morning. Take a look at the method I added, that should get you what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149281/discussion-between-cchandler81-and-manish).